# Scrapy spider not crawling the required pages

Tags: python, scrapy

Here is the website link I am trying to crawl.
http://search.epfoservices.in/est_search_display_result.php?pageNum_search=1&totalRows_search=72045&old_rg_id=AP&office_name=&pincode=&estb_code=&estb_name=&paging=paging
And below is my **scraper**,as this is one of the first attempts to **scraping**, so pardon for silly mistakes. Kindly have a look and suggest any changes which would make my code running.

**Items.py**

```
import scrapy


class EpfoCrawl2Item(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    from scrapy.item import Item, Field
    S_No = Field()
    Old_region_code = Field()
    Region_code = Field()
    Name = Field()
    Address = Field()
    Pin = Field()
    Epfo_office = Field()
    Under_Ro = Field()
    Under_Acc = Field()
    Payment = Field()
    pass
```

**epfocrawl1_spider.py**

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector


class EpfoCrawlSpider(scrapy.Spider):
"""Spider for regularly updated search.epfoservices.in"""
name = "PfData"
allowed_domains = ["search.epfoservices.in"]
starturls = ["http://search.epfoservices.in/est_search_display_result.php?pageNum_search=1&totalRows_search=72045&old_rg_id=AP&office_name=&pincode=&estb_code=&estb_name=&paging=paging"]

def parse(self,response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    rows = hxs.select('//tr"]')
    items = []
    for val in rows:
        item = Val()
        item['S_no'] = val.select('/td[0]/text()').extract()
        item['Old_region_code'] = val.select('/td[1]/text').extract()
        item['Region_code'] = val.select('/td[2]/text()').extract()
        item['Name'] = val.select('/td[3]/text()').extract()
        item['Address'] = val.select('/td[4]/text()').extract()
        item['Pin'] = val.select('/td[5]/text()').extract()
        item['Epfo_office'] = val.select('/td[6]/text()').extract()
        item['Under_ro'] = val.select('/td[7]/text()').extract()
        item['Under_Acc'] = val.select('/td[8]/text()').extract()
        item['Payment'] = val.select('a/@href').extract()
        items.append(item)
        yield items
```

**And below is the log** after running "scrapy crawl PfData"

```
016-05-25 13:45:11+0530 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: 
2016-05-25 13:45:11+0530 [PfData] INFO: Spider opened
2016-05-25 13:45:11+0530 [PfData] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-05-25 13:45:11+0530 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2016-05-25 13:45:11+0530 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 127.0.0.1:6080
2016-05-25 13:45:11+0530 [PfData] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2016-05-25 13:45:11+0530 [PfData] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
    {'finish_reason': 'finished',
     'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 25, 8, 15, 11, 343313),
     'log_count/DEBUG': 2,
     'log_count/INFO': 7,
     'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 25, 8, 15, 11, 341872)}
2016-05-25 13:45:11+0530 [PfData] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Suggestions are requested.

Comment: @abukaj No! Code Review requires working code. This code doesn't work as intended.

Comment: The lack of indentation after `class EpfoCrawlSpider(scrapy.Spider):` is never going to work either. Indentation is important in Python.

Comment: @Mast is not inspecting source code to debug it a code review?

Comment: @abukaj Perhaps that's *a* version of reviewing code, but it's [off-topic](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for codereview.se. Please, do not recommend SE sites if you're unfamiliar with their scope.

Comment: @Mast Thanks. I have checked only description of codereview.se which is rather short, not the offtopic policy.

Answer (score 0):

the start urls list has to be `start_urls` and not `starturls`